# Jira Rest API retrieve assignee displayName

Tags: jira-rest-api, insomnia

I am using Jira API in Insomnia to retrieve tickets.  Now I want to limit the fields returned.  One field I want to return is assignee displayName.  I have tried many different syntax.  I can get the entire assignee object but there is much there I do not want.  Here is a sample.  I have tried

- assignee.displayName
- assignee?.displayName
- assignee:displayName

  "assignee": {

  ```
   "accountId": "xx",
   "accountType": "xx",
   "active": true,
   "avatarUrls": {
       "16x16": "xx",
       "24x24": "xx",
       "32x32": "xx",
       "48x48": "xx"
   },
   "displayName": "xx",
   "emailAddress": "xx",
   "self": "xx",
   "timeZone": "xx"
  ```

  },

I want to get just displayName from assignee.  Does the API not allow this?

Comment: Please edit your question and add a tag for the coding language you're using to interact with Jira API.